# use buttons to check two or more radio groups

Tags: javascript, html

I hope somebody can help me, as I have searched for a solution, and tried many different things - and I'm stuck!

This [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jesterwatch/nwo706xw/108/) may also demonstrate

My code is

```js
$("#button_1").click(function() {
  $("INPUT[name=type]").val(['1']);
});

$("#button_2").click(function() {
  $("INPUT[name=type]").val(['2']);
});

$("#button_3").click(function() {
  $("INPUT[name=type]").val(['3']);
});
```

```html
<button id="button_1">check both blue radios</button>
<button id="button_2">check both red radios</button>
<button id="button_3">check both yellow radios</button>
<br>
<br>
<div id='type'>
  <label for="radio_1">blue dial</label>
  <input type='radio' id='radio_1' name='type' value='1' />
  <label for="radio_2">red dial</label>
  <input type='radio' id='radio_2' name='type' value='2' />
  <label for="radio_3">yellow dial</label>
  <input type='radio' id='radio_3' name='type' value='3' />
</div>

<br>
<br>
<div id='type'>
  <label for="radio_1">blue strap</label>
  <input type='radio' id='radio_1' name='type' value='1' />
  <label for="radio_2">red strap</label>
  <input type='radio' id='radio_2' name='type' value='2' />
  <label for="radio_3">yellow strap</label>
  <input type='radio' id='radio_3' name='type' value='3' />
</div>
```

What I am after doing is clicking a button and checking the relevant TWO radio buttons below.

I'm new here, so any help would be appreciated - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your inputs have the same name attribute.

By the way, I changed two other things :

- ID attributes
  ID attributes must be unique ! Even if you don't use it.
- User jQuery [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) function to set / unset the `checked` propety

  ```js
  $("#button_1").click(function() {
   $('input[value="1"]').prop('checked', true);
  });

  $("#button_2").click(function() {
    $('input[value="2"]').prop('checked', true);
  });

  $("#button_3").click(function() {
    $('input[value="3"]').prop('checked', true);
  });
  ```

  ```html
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <button id="button_1">check both blue radios</button>
  <button id="button_2">check both red radios</button>
  <button id="button_3">check both yellow radios</button>
  <br>
  <br>
  <div id='type'>
    <label for="dial_1">blue dial</label>
    <input type='radio' id='dial_1' name='dial' value='1' />
    <label for="dial_2">red dial</label>
    <input type='radio' id='dial_2' name='dial' value='2' />
    <label for="dial_3">yellow dial</label>
    <input type='radio' id='dial_3' name='dial' value='3' />
  </div>

  <br>
  <br>
  <div id='type'>
    <label for="strap_1">blue strap</label>
    <input type='radio' id='strap_1' name='strap' value='1' />
    <label for="strap_2">red strap</label>
    <input type='radio' id='strap_2' name='strap' value='2' />
    <label for="strap_3">yellow strap</label>
    <input type='radio' id='strap_3' name='strap' value='3' />
  </div>
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Try this May be it will solve your problem:-

```html
<form>
    <fieldset id="group1">
        <input type="radio" value="" name="group1">
        <input type="radio" value="" name="group1">
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset id="group2">
        <input type="radio" value="" name="group2">
        <input type="radio" value="" name="group2">
        <input type="radio" value="" name="group2">
    </fieldset>
</form>
```